# RoR ActiveRecord :through is performing the join backwards - are my relationships bad?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have three tables: Devices, Actions, and ActionTypes.  ActionTypes is a lookup table -  nothing but a name and id.  Here are the relationships:

**Device**

```
has_many :actions
has_many :action_types, :through => :actions
has_many :tasks
```

**Action**

```
belongs_to :device
has_one :action_type
```

**ActionType**

```
has_many :actions
has_many :devices, :through => :actions
```

I'm very new to Rails, so I have the feeling these relationships are not correct - my goal is to be able to use something like @device.action_types, which this is ALMOST doing, but this is the SQL it generates in that case:

```
SELECT "action_types".* FROM "action_types" INNER JOIN "actions" ON "action_types"."action_id" = "actions"."id" WHERE "actions"."device_id" = 1
```

This would be perfect, except it should join on action_types.id = actions.action_type_id instead.  There is no actiontypes.action_id (and there shouldn't be), and I understand that AR is looking for it because of my relationships... I'm just not sure which part is wrong!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the table actions to have an action_type_id, then your model Action need:

`belongs_to :action_type`

A useful resource to read is the rails guide about associations: [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)